# Why is this for loop not returning the intended output?

Tags: javascript

This is just an exercise in a course, this app selects a random fruit from the fruits array and then the removeItem() function is supposed to remove that one from the array and returns the modified array, but I'm getting a weird output, and the function is not working.

The problem can be seen here

```js
function randomFruit(importedArray) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * importedArray.length);
  return importedArray[random];
}

function removeItem(importedArray, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < importedArray.length; i++) {
    if (importedArray[i] === item) {
      importedArray.splice(i, 1);
      return [...importedArray.slice(0, i), ...importedArray.slice(i + 1)];
    } else {
      return "not found";
    }
  }
}

function makeFruitArray() {
  var foods = ["", "", "", "", ""];
  return foods;
}

let fruitArray = makeFruitArray();
let fruitItem = randomFruit(fruitArray);
let remaining = removeItem(fruitArray, fruitItem);

console.log({fruitArray, fruitItem, remaining});
```

Comment: Please post the output as text here instead of links to images, so it's easier for us to understand what's "wrong".

Comment: sorry I changed it 

Comment: You should explain in English what the actual problem is: "When a cherry is picked, it seems to also remove the watermelon from the list". Try to minimize the work others will have to do when scanning through your question.

Comment: Thanks you for the advice, I'm learning and will take that to account when asking questions in the future

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with React. I added a live example you can use that demonstrates your non-working code. You should always to remove any code that is not related to the problem

Comment: Please try to write a title that help distinguish your question from other similar questions on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two major problems:

- Your `for` loop in `removeItem` was always returning on the first iteration
- You were modifying the initial array as you removed items from it

I've also removed all the unnecessary code used to reproduce your problem.

```js
function randomFruit(importedArray) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * importedArray.length);
  return importedArray[random];
}

function removeItem(importedArray, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < importedArray.length; i++) {
    if (importedArray[i] === item) {
      // Don't modify the original array since we want to
      // display the original fruits  
      return [...importedArray.slice(0, i), ...importedArray.slice(i + 1)];
    }
  }
  // Error condition goes outside the loop, not inside.
  return null;
}

function makeFruitArray() {
  var foods = ["", "", "", "", ""];
  return foods;
}

let fruitArray = makeFruitArray();
let fruitItem = randomFruit(fruitArray);
let remaining = removeItem(fruitArray, fruitItem);

console.log({fruitArray, fruitItem, remaining});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in the `removeItem` function -

1. If the random one is not the first item on the array, the function returns `not found`. It wouldn't run for the second loop at all, as your function returns `not found` after the first iteration.
2. The `splice` method updates the original array. While you are passing the `fruitArray` to the `removeItem` method, it gets passed as reference and updating it within the function using `splice` will update the actual array as well.

The simplest and safest way of removing an item from an array would be -

```js
function removeItem(importedArray, item) {
  const filteredArray = importedArray.filter((each) => each !== item);
  if (filteredArray.length === 0) return 'Not Found';
  return filteredArray;
}
```

Comment: There will be an issue if there are two items of the same type (value).

Comment: Why are you suggesting that splice should not be used? Using filter to remove an element may cause it to scan the entire array even if it finds a match at the first element. No need for the includes test, is there? There's a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: @RonHillel From the question and the OP's code, it doesn't look like there would be two items of the same type.

Comment: @JuanMendes you are right. It was not the most performant solution. I have updated it. This would most likely address the problems you mentioned.

Comment: @himayan It still suffers from the problem you actually mentioned  You are modifying an array that you were using for displaying the full list, you can create a new array spreading the array as you suggested before. I was just saying that you weren't explaining why they shouldn't modify the array in place (because of the bug I just mentioned)

Comment: @JuanMendes I got confused as well. `filter` seems like the best way to do this. The `includes` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As [himayan said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261028/why-is-this-for-loop-not-returning-the-intended-output/72261285#72261285), the issue was that splice already changes the array.

Here's my solution:

```
function removeItem(importedArray, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < importedArray.length; i++) {
    if (importedArray[i] === item) {
      importedArray.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }

  return importedArray;
}
```

Comment: But if you modify the array, then the display the existing array will be broken...

Comment: It's in the function scope, not the app scope. The function doesn't need a record of the original array afterward.

Comment: It does need it, it displays the original array also. I've made your code runnable so you can see how it doesn't work.

Comment: :) It does work. It's not displaying the array in the removeItem function scope...

Comment: @RonHillel `importedArray` is a reference to the original array; this modifies the original array. That's why the OP was spreading into a new array.

Comment: You are confused, whether the variable is local or global does not matter. Both global and local variables could be pointing to the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Your remove item function is not working correctly. Instead of writing loops and splicing the array to create a new one you should just use the `filter` method

```
function removeItem(importedArray, item) {
    let newArray = importedArray.filter(function (element) {
        return element !== item;
    });
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: yes, slightly slow since there's no need to scan the entire array, but it works

Comment: @JuanMendes Can you please explain why is this solution slower?

Comment: I think it's because I am scanning the entire array which has n complexity. There might be a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes, it's because if you use a regular `for` loop, you can exit the loop as soon as you find your item whereas `filter` will keep iterating over the entire array.